# Do Extension Methods Hide Dependencies?

Tags: c#-3.0, inversion-of-control, extension-methods, dependencies, testability

All,

Wanted to get a few thoughts on this.  Lately I am becoming more and more of a subscriber of "purist" DI/IOC principles when designing/developing. Part of this (a big part) involves making sure there is little coupling between my classes, and that their dependencies are resolved via the constructor (there are certainly other ways of managing this, but you get the idea).

My basic premise is that extension methods violate the principles of DI/IOC.

I created the following extension method that I use to ensure that the strings inserted into database tables are truncated to the right size:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TruncateToSize(this string input, int maxLength)
    {
        int lengthToUse = maxLength;
        if (input.Length < maxLength)
        {
            lengthToUse = input.Length;
        }

        return input.Substring(0, lengthToUse);
    }
}
```

I can then call my string from within another class like so:

```
string myString = "myValue.TruncateThisPartPlease.";
myString.TruncateToSize(8);
```

A fair translation of this without using an extension method would be:

```
string myString = "myValue.TruncateThisPartPlease.";
StaticStringUtil.TruncateToSize(myString, 8);
```

Any class that uses either of the above examples could not be tested independently of the class that contains the TruncateToSize method (TypeMock aside). If I were not using an extension method, and I did not want to create a static dependency, it would look more like:

```
string myString = "myValue.TruncateThisPartPlease.";
_stringUtil.TruncateToSize(myString, 8);
```

In the last example, the _stringUtil dependency would be resolved via the constructor and the class could be tested with no dependency on the actual TruncateToSize method's class (it could be easily mocked).

From my perspective, the first two examples rely on static dependencies (one explicit, one hidden), while the second inverts the dependency and provides reduced coupling and better testability.

So does the use of extension methods conflict with DI/IOC principles?  If you're a subscriber of IOC methodology, do you avoid using extension methods?

Comment: @antisanity: AFAIK it is logically impossible for an extension method's instance parameter (*input* in this case) to be null.

Comment: Just for the sake of being a purist, the word static anywhere in the code breaks you object oriented design and violates most principles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I see where you are coming from, however, if you are trying to mock out the functionality of an extension method, I believe you are using them incorrectly. Extension methods should be used to perform a task that would simply be inconvenient syntactically without them. Your TruncateToLength is a good example.

Testing TruncateToLength would not involve mocking it out, it would simply involve the creation of a few strings and testing that the method actually returned the proper value.

On the other hand, if you have code in your data layer contained in extension methods that is accessing your data store, then yes, you have a problem and testing is going to become an issue.

I typically only use extension methods in order to provide syntactic sugar for small, simple operations.

Answer (score 18):

I think it's fine - because it's not like `TruncateToSize` is a realistically replaceable component. It's a method which will only ever need to do a single thing.

You don't need to be able to mock out *everything* - just services which either disrupt unit testing (file access etc) or ones which you want to test in terms of genuine dependencies. If you were using it to perform authentication or something like that, it would be a very different matter... but just doing a straight string operation which has absolutely no configurability, different implementation options etc - there's no point in viewing that as a dependency in the normal sense.

To put it another way: if `TruncateToSize` were a genuine member of `String`, would you even think twice about using it? Do you try to mock out integer arithmetic as well, introducing `IInt32Adder` etc? Of course not. This is just the same, it's only that you happen to be supplying the implementation. Unit test the heck out of `TruncateToSize` and don't worry about it.

Comment: So, I don't disagree with your answer--it's very pragmatic.  You can definitely take IOC (or any design theory) too far.

For the sake of argument: assuming you are committed to IOC, you would have no problem with the second implementation example (the explicit dependency on a static class)?  I have never read an article by a hardcore advocate of IOC that said static dependencies are acceptable.

Comment: What if there was two algorithms for TruncateToSize? One which trades speed for memory, and one that trades memory for speed. Wouldn't it be better in that case if it had an interface? And since you can't predict the need for these, shouldn't you simply make it an interface in the first place?

Comment: @didibus: Following that logic to its conclusion, every single method should have its own interface. No, there are some predictions it *is* reasonable to make. You have to be pragmatic in software, or you'll never get anything done and your code will be far more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods, partial classes and dynamic objects. I really like them, however you must tread carefully , there be monsters here.

I would take a look at dynamic languages and see how they cope with these sort of problems on a day to day basis, its really enlightening. Especially when they have nothing to stop them from doing stupid things apart from good design and discipline. Everything is dynamic at run time, the only thing to stop them is the computer throwing a major run time error. "Duck Typing" is the maddest thing I have ever seen, good code is down to good program design, respect for others in your team, and the trust that every member, although have the ability to do some wacky things choose not to because good design leads to better results.

As for your test scenario with mock objects/ICO/DI, would you really put some heavy duty work in an extension method or just some simple static stuff that operate in a functional type way? I tend to use them like you would in a functional programming style, input goes in, results come out with no magic in the middle, just straight up framework classes that you know the guys at MS have designed and tested :P that you can rely on.

If your are doing some heavy lifting stuff using extension methods I would look at your program design again, check out your CRC designs, Class models, Use Cases, DFD's, action diagrams or whatever you like to use and figure out where in this design you planned to put this stuff in an extension method instead of a proper class.

At the end of the day, you can only test against your system design and not code outside of your scope. If you going to use extension classes, my advice would be to look at Object Composition models instead and use inheritance only when there is a very good reason.

Object Composition always wins out with me as they produce solid code. You can plug them in, take them out and do what you like with them. Mind you this all depends on whether you use Interfaces or not as part of your design. Also if you use Composition classes, the class hierarchy tree gets flattened into discrete classes and there are fewer places where your extension method will be picked up through inherited classes.

If you must use a class that acts upon another class as is the case with extension methods, look at the visitor pattern first and decide if its a better route.

Answer (score 0):

Its a pain because they are hard to mock. I usually use one of these strategies

1. Yep, scrap the extension its a PITA to mock out
2. Use the extension and just test that it did the right thing. i.e. pass data into the truncate and check it got truncated
3. If it's not some trivial thing, and I HAVE to mock it, I'll make my extension class have a setter for the service it uses, and set that in the test code.

i.e.

```
static class TruncateExtensions{

    public ITruncateService Service {private get;set;}
    public string TruncateToSize(string s, int size)
    {
         return (Service ?? Service = new MyDefaultTranslationServiceImpl()). TruncateToSize(s, size);
    }
}
```

This is a bit scary because someone might set the service when they shouldn't, but I'm a little cavalier sometimes, and if it was really important, I could do something clever with #if TEST flags, or the ServiceLocator pattern to avoid the setter being used in production.